# ToString on Expression Trees produces badly formatted output

Tags: c#, expression-trees, tostring

When I use `Expression.ToString()` to convert an Expression Tree into human readable form, the result is something like this:

```
x => ((x.ID > 2) OrElse (x.ID != 6))
x => ((x.ID > 2) AndAlso (x.ID != 6))
```

Ideally, I would want the output to show the operators instead of "OrElse" and "AndAlso":

```
x => ((x.ID > 2) || (x.ID != 6))
x => ((x.ID > 2) && (x.ID != 6))
```

As a workaround, I could use the `string.Replace()` method..

```
.Replace("AndAlso", "&&")
.Replace("OrElse", "||")
```

but that has obvious weaknesses and seems awkward.
Also I do not want to create a large 'Replace'-section or huge regex-tree simply to get the formatting right.

Is there a simple way to get a code-like human-readable form of expression trees?

Comment: Since Expressions aren't C# specific, I don't know of another way to have it output C#-exact syntax. I think your best best is to indeed use the `String.Replace` method. If you're worried about possible false positives on variable names that are similar, try matching with the surrounding spaces `.Replace(" AndAlso ", " && ")` EDIT: Regarding _why_ you're looking for a replacement, just place this conversion behaviour into shared utility methods. That way if you need to add a new `Replace` you can do it in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the simplest way to do this correctly would be to write your own `ExpressionVisitor` class which produces the C#-formatted output code.

The simplest way to do this is to use the [ExpressionStringBuilder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs#240c0ae863272266) from the reference sources as a starting point and to tweak it until you are happy with the output result.

Comment: There is no need in using ILSpy here. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs#240c0ae863272266

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't care to check if the sources are published :)

Answer (score 0):

When I'm interested in the *semantics* of the code represented by the expression, rather than the exact syntax tree, I've found it very useful to compile it to an Assembly and view that in ILSpy. Convenience method:

```
// Code is probably adapted from some other answer, don't remember
public static void CompileToAssemblyFile(
  this LambdaExpression expression,
  string outputFilePath = null,
  string assemblyAndModuleName = null,
  string typeName = "TheType",
  string methodName = "TheMethod",
  // Adjust this
  string ilSpyPath = @"C:\path\to\ILSpy.exe")
{
  assemblyAndModuleName = assemblyAndModuleName ?? nameof(CompileToAssemblyFile);

  outputFilePath = outputFilePath ??
                   Path.Combine(
                     Path.GetTempPath(),
                     $"{assemblyAndModuleName}_{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss}_{Guid.NewGuid()}.dll");

  var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  var asmName = new AssemblyName {Name = assemblyAndModuleName};

  var asmBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    asmName,
    AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave,
    Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFilePath));

  string outputFileName = Path.GetFileName(outputFilePath);

  var module = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
    assemblyAndModuleName,
    outputFileName,
    true);

  var typeBuilder = module.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);

  var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
    methodName,
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
    expression.ReturnType,
    expression.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type).ToArray());

  var pdbGenerator = DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator();

  expression.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder, pdbGenerator);

  typeBuilder.CreateType();

  asmBuilder.Save(outputFileName);

  Process.Start(ilSpyPath, outputFilePath);
}
```

(This is not very faithful to the syntax tree because it goes through both the `Expression` -> IL translation done by the LambdaCompiler, and the IL -> C# decompilation by ILSpy. OTOH, it can improve readability by converting some gotos into loops, and by producing actual C#.)

This will fail if the `Expression` contains "non-trivial constants" (live objects); but for that one could write a visitor that replaces constants by new variables and then lambda-abstracts these variables at the toplevel.