# Practical Solution for using ExpressionTree in WCF projects

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, serialization, expression-trees

I want to use Expresstion Trees in WCF Projects

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetByPredicate")]
    List<Person> Get(Expression<Func<Person,bool>> expression);
    [OperationContract]
    List<Person> Get();
}
```

but ExpresstionTrees can not be serialized in WCF

so I searched and found some solutions but all failed

1. using [Linq.Serialize](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) BUT I can`t [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435468/serialize-linq-does-not-work-in-wcf-proxy-layer)
2. using [ExpressionSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613766/could-not-find-a-matching-type-in-expressionserialization-dll) BUT I can`t [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613766/could-not-find-a-matching-type-in-expressionserialization-dll)
3. using ExpressionTree.ToString() and [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) (Convert Expression Trees to String and vice versa) BUT I can`t [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438154/tostring-on-expression-trees-produces-badly-formatted-output) & [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436811/convert-expression-tree-to-string-and-vice-versa-for-wcf) & [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459981/expression-tree-tostring-method-generates-strange-string-why)

all is unsuccessful so

**Can anyone guide me and give me a practical solution that I can use it without problem ?** (Serialize and Deserialize Expression Trees without problem & hardness)